# Swipeable Inline Buttons Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have an ordered inline list of buttons that I've made to go off the screen. I want to make these buttons swipe able so you can find the ones going off screen.

```
   <style>
    .banner-test {
        transition: all 0.4s ease;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: auto;
        padding: .625em .850em;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 100;
        bottom: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        /* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
        background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        /* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        /* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
        filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);
        /* For IE 8*/
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
    }
    .ui-btn {
        background: #f6f6f6;
        border-color: #ddd;
        color: #333;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #f3f3f3;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: .5em 0;
        padding: .7em 1em;
        display: block;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
    .ui-btn:link {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .ui-btn-inline {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin-right: .625em;
    }
    .swiper-holder {
        width: 170%;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .swiper-holder div {
        width: 16%;
        display: inline;
    }
</style>
<div class="banner-test">
    <div class="swiper-holder">
        <div><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">Button</a></div>
        <div><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">Button</a></div>
        <div><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">Button</a></div>
        <div><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">Button</a></div>
        <div><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">Button</a></div>
        <div><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">Button</a></div>
        <div><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">Button</a></div>
        <div><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">Button</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to do this directly in jQuery? I've had a look and found out about touchend, touchstart etc. but I really don't know where to start with this and will this be supported on most browsers?

There is nothing on the web about this and I haven't really seen anyone else do this.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ye2q5ede/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try out this plugin http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/index.html

It gives you all type of touch events and works well on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

This is a method that holds the buttons in a wrapper and when the browsers window gets to a lower width, it will enable a scroll bar that you can swipe with your finger on mobile.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Select">
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Select">
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Select">
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Select">
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Select">
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Select">
     <input type="button" class="button" value="Select">
</div>
```

CSS

```
    body {
      background-color: #333;
    }
    .wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      overflow-x: auto;
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
      padding: 1rem;
      background-color: #ccc;
    }

.internal {
  display: inline;
  background-color: wheat;
  &:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: hotpink;
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3m59pxt3/)